# iOS - strangeness in the navigationController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have createa an app that is based on "Single View Application" Xcode template. It has a navigation controller and a rootViewController.

When I am on the rootViewController and I do

```
[self presentModalViewController:nextModalViewController animated:YES];
```

the new view controller is animated in.

My problem is this. I have presented a lot of viewControllers in sequence, that is

```
A > B > C > D
```

or in other words, I have presented B from A using presentModalViewController, C from B and so one. Yes, I have to use presentModalViewController because I have a special animation going on to transition between viewControllers and I cannot use [self.navigationController push...

My question is: what happens when I use presentModalViewController regarding to the navigation stack? Is the controller being presented pushed to some stack? is there a way to obtain references to all navigationControllers that were presented at a given time? something like that navigation stack? I mean, suppose I am on D and I want to get a list of all controllers presented before D.

I know I can create properties and pass that along. I am just wondering if theres something already built on iOS that does that.

thanks.

Comment: One thing to note, is that presentModalViewController is a method on all UIViewControllers (and deprecated in ios6!).  If you're only calling presentModalViewController, and never using the UINavigationController-specific calls like pushViewController, then you should consider a refactor.      In this refactor I would suggest changing UINavigationController to a standard UIViewController, and using the presentViewController:animated:completion: method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 5 and later, `UIViewController` has a `presentingViewController` property that returns the view controller that presents the receiver. In iOS 4 and earlier, use the `parentViewController` property of the presented view controller to access its presenting view controller. So you can access, for example, the C view controller from D by accessing these properties appropriately. [See the docs for further information.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

If you want to access all the view controllers as in a chain, you can do this:

```
UIViewController *node = self;
while (node != nil) {
    // do something with the view controller, then skip to its parent
    node = node.presentingViewController;
    // or node = node.parentViewController; in iOS 4 or older
}
```

Comment: @RubberDuck Thanks :) I'm glad to have helped.

Answer (score -1):

I'd subsequently check the size of the `viewControllers` property from your UINavigationController after every modal presentation, and check if it grows or not.

```
UIViewController *theControllerYouWant = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:(theIndexOfYourViewController)];
```

Comment: no. this property just shows the rootViewController and do not grows.